# how to convert jndi lookup from xml to java config

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

Currently I'm converting the xml to java config. But I stuck at some part that I have been research for several days. Here the problem:

Xml config:

```
     <jee:jndi-lookup id="dbDataSource" jndi-name="${db.jndi}" resource-ref="true" />

     <beans:bean id="jdbcTemplate"
     class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate" >
     <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dbDataSource"></beans:property>
     </beans:bean>
```

So far I managed to convert this code:

`<jee:jndi-lookup id="dbDataSource" jndi-name="${db.jndi}" resource-ref="true" />`

to this :

```
@Bean(name = "dbDataSource")
public JndiObjectFactoryBean dataSource() {
   JndiObjectFactoryBean bean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
   bean.setJndiName("${db.jndi}");
   bean.setResourceRef(true); 
   return bean; 
}
```

And this :

```
     <beans:bean id="jdbcTemplate"
     class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate" >
     <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dbDataSource"></beans:property>
     </beans:bean>
```

to this:

```
@Bean(name = "jdbcTemplate")
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() { 
   JdbcTemplate jt = new JdbcTemplate();
    jt.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return jt;
   }
```

The problem is the method **setDataSource()** need DataSource object but I'm not sure how to relate both bean.How to pass the JndiObjectFactoryBean to DataSource?

Or do I need to use another method?

Extra Question:

The `bean.setJndiName("${db.jndi}")` , ***${db.jndi}*** is refer to properties file but I always got NameNotFoundException, How to make it work?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Instead of `JndiObjectFactoryBean` use a `JndiDataSourceLookup` instead. To use the `${db.jndi}` in the method declare a method argument and annotate it with `@Value`.

```
@Bean(name = "dbDataSource")
public DataSource dataSource(@Value("${db.jndi}") String jndiName) {
    JndiDataSourceLookup lookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
    return lookup.getDataSource(jndiName);
}
```

> Autowired methods and constructors can also use the `@Value` annotation. -- Spring Reference Guide.

`@Bean` methods are basically factory methods which are also auto wired methods and as such fall into this category.

In your factory method for the `JdbcTemplate` you can simply use a `DataSource` method argument to get a reference to the datasource (If you have multiple you can use the `@Qualifier` on the method argument to specify which one you want to use).

```
@Bean
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource ds) { 
    return new JdbcTemplate(ds);
}
```

Comment: thanks is working but need to add String after `@Value("${db.jndi}"`

Comment: Typed it from my head, missed the `String`, fixed now.

Comment: Bracket missed after @Value("${db.jndi}" but I can't fix it because stackoverflow doesn't allow to fix one char(((