# How convert <jee:jndi-lookup> to Spring JavaConfig in a Websphere Environment

Tags: java, spring, websphere, jndi

I have an old Spring xml config.

```
<jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="ree/configuration" cache="true" id="re-properties-config" />
```

In the WebSphere 8 i have a "Resource Environment Providers" and a "Resource environment entry" under the JNDI name "ree/configuration". The  Referenceables class is java.util.Properties.

With xml config everything works. "Resource environment entry" from WebSphere mapped in a Properties Object.

Now i want migrate to Spring JavaConfig.
What is the best solution?

I try this:

```
private static Properties jndiProperties() {
    Properties properties = null;
    JndiTemplate jndi = new JndiTemplate();
    try {
        properties = (Properties)jndi.lookup("ree/configuration");
        LOG.info("JNDI Properties loaded: " + properties);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        LOG.error("NamingException for ree/configuration", e);
    }
    return properties;
}
```

but it failed with a ClassCastException. javax.naming.Reference cannot cast to java.util.Properties

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code to get Properties form the returned Reference :

```
            Reference ref = jndi.lookup("ree/configuration");
            Enumeration e = ref.getAll();
            while( e.hasMoreElements() )
            {
               RefAddr ra = (RefAddr) e.nextElement();
               properties.put( ra.getType().toLowerCase(), ra.getContent() );
            }
```

For more examples on how to use Reference, try this link: http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/javax.naming.Reference

Comment: I have this solution also found. I thought there is something more comfortable  :-)

Comment: OK. Glad to know the suggested answer does in fact work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Related to [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34757609/how-to-convert-jndi-lookup-from-xml-to-java-config).

You can define a `@Configuration` class and create a bean like this.

```
@Bean(name = "dbDataSource")
public DataSource dataSource(@Value("${db.jndi}" String jndiName) {
    JndiDataSourceLookup lookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
    return lookup.getDataSource(jndiName);
}
```

You can also inyect the `JNDI` from properties without recieving as a input parameter,

Answer (score 0):

You can define a @Configuration class and create a bean like this.

```
@Bean
public JndiObjectFactoryBean rePropertiesConfig() {
    JndiObjectFactoryBean bean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
    bean.setJndiName("ree/configuration");
    bean.setCache(true);
    
    return bean;
}
```

and in the @Bean where you use the jndi object you have to cast it:

```
Properties properties = (Properties) rePropertiesConfig().getObject();
```